# How to lowercase every element of a collection efficiently?

Tags: java, string, lowercase

What's the most efficient way to lower case every element of a List or Set?

My idea for a List:

```
final List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("HELLO");
strings.add("WORLD");

for(int i=0,l=strings.size();i<l;++i)
{
  strings.add(strings.remove(0).toLowerCase());
}
```

Is there a better, faster way? How would this example look like for a Set? As there is currently no method for applying an operation to each element of a Set (or List) can it be done without creating an additional temporary Set?

Something like this would be nice:

```
Set<String> strings = new HashSet<String>();
strings.apply(
  function (element)
  { this.replace(element, element.toLowerCase();) } 
);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This seems like a fairly clean solution for lists.  It should allow for the particular List implementation being used to provide an implementation that is optimal for both the traversal of the list--in linear time--and the replacing of the string--in constant time.

```
public static void replace(List<String> strings)
{
    ListIterator<String> iterator = strings.listIterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        iterator.set(iterator.next().toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

---

This is the best that I can come up with for sets.  As others have said, the operation cannot be performed in-place in the set for a number of reasons.  The lower-case string may need to be placed in a different location in the set than the string it is replacing.  Moreover, the lower-case string may not be added to the set at all if it is identical to another lower-case string that has already been added (e.g., "HELLO" and "Hello" will both yield "hello", which will only be added to the set once).

```
public static void replace(Set<String> strings)
{
    String[] stringsArray = strings.toArray(new String[0]);
    for (int i=0; i<stringsArray.length; ++i)
    {
        stringsArray[i] = stringsArray[i].toLowerCase();
    }
    strings.clear();
    strings.addAll(Arrays.asList(stringsArray));
}
```

Comment: Referring to your first solution: how would one return a ListIterator as List?

Comment: @rookie, Your question isn't clear. Are you asking how to use a ListIterator as a List? If so, then you can't. An Iterator is not a collection, but a pointer into one.

Comment: With Java 8, the first example can be simplified to `strings.replaceAll(String::toLowerCase);` You could do a similar thing with the second, using `Arrays.asList(stringsArray).replaceAll(String::toLowerCase);`

Comment: This solution (for Lists) will fail with an `UnsupportedOperationException` on `iterator.set()` if the List passed is a `SingletonList`.

Answer (score 131):

Yet another solution, but with Java 8 and above:

```
List<String> result = strings.stream()
                             .map(String::toLowerCase)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Though this is more elegant, this is not the more performant solution. [Angelica's benchmark](https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html) for finding the max value in a list of boxed ints:

ArrayList, for-loop : 6.55 ms
ArrayList, seq. stream: 8.33 ms

Comment: @thisisananth a benchmark (if we dare to call the undocumented methodology a benchmark) of an operation that searches for a maximum in an `int[]` array, is entirely unrelated to an operation converting a collection of strings to lower case. A list of boxed ints would be a `List<Integer>`, by the way, but that linked article uses `int[]`, which is an array of primitive ints. And since that will yield an `IntStream`, a serious developer would use `max()` rather than `reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Math::max)` for that.

Comment: Also if there is really large List it should be mentioned that there is an parrallelStream that can improve the performance for larger list.

Answer (score 13):

You can do this with Google Collections:

```
    Collection<String> lowerCaseStrings = Collections2.transform(strings,
        new Function<String, String>() {
            public String apply(String str) {
                return str.toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are fine with changing the input list here is one more way to achieve it.

`strings.replaceAll(String::toLowerCase)`

Comment: This won't work with immutable collections, like ones created using List.of(). Although, an elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is no real elegant solution due to two facts:

- `String`s in Java are immutable
- Java gives you no real nice `map(f, list)` function as you have in functional languages.

Asymptotically speaking, you can't get a better run time than your current method. You will have to create a new string using `toLowerCase()` and you will need to iterate by yourself over the list and generate each new lower-case string, replacing it with the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably faster:

```
for(int i=0,l=strings.size();i<l;++i)
{
  strings.set(i, strings.get(i).toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: This is fine for an `ArrayList`, but the performance is `O(N^2)` for a `LinkedList`.

Comment: Yes. for yours, the opposit is true.

Comment: Sorry, for the original algorithm, the opposit is true.

Answer (score 2):

Try [CollectionUtils#transform in Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#transform(java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer)) for an in-place solution, or [Collections2#transform in Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#transform(java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) if you need a live view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to do the manipulation in place (without creating another Collection) if you change strings to be a Set. This is because you can only iterate over the Set using an iterator or a for each loop, and cannot insert new objects whilst doing so (it throws an exception)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the ListIterator method in the accepted (Matthew T. Staebler's) solution. How is using the ListIterator better than the method here?

```
public static Set<String> replace(List<String> strings) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (String s: strings)
        set.add(s.toLowerCase());
    return set;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for similar stuff, but was stuck because my ***ArrayList*** object was not declared as **GENERIC** and it was available as raw **List** type object from somewhere. I was just getting an ***ArrayList*** object "_products". So, what I did is mentioned below and it worked for me perfectly ::

```
List<String> dbProducts = _products;
    for(int i = 0; i<dbProducts.size(); i++) {
        dbProducts.add(dbProducts.get(i).toLowerCase());         
    }
```

That is, I first took my available **_products** and made a **GENERIC** list object (As I were getting only strings in same) then I applied the **toLowerCase()** method on list elements which was not working previously because of non-generic ***ArrayList*** object.

And the method ***toLowerCase()*** we are using here is of **String** class.

> String java.lang.String.toLowerCase()

not of **ArrayList** or **Object** class.

Please correct if m wrong. Newbie in JAVA seeks guidance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using JAVA 8 parallel stream it becomes faster

```
List<String> output= new ArrayList<>();
List<String> input= new ArrayList<>();
input.add("A");
input.add("B");
input.add("C");
input.add("D");
input.stream().parallel().map((item) -> item.toLowerCase())
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> output));
```

Comment: The order of strings in the result will be different

Answer (score 0):

Have used Java8 **streams** for **lowercase** of every element in a Collection.

```
List<String> groupNamesList =  new ArrayList<>();
groupNamesList.add("GroupOne");
groupNamesList.add("GroupTwo");
groupNamesList.add("GroupThree");
groupNamesList = groupNamesList.stream().map(groupName -> groupName.toLowerCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output:

```
[groupone,grouptwo,groupthree]
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
private static void getOccuranceCount() {
    List<String> listdemo=Arrays.asList("saradhi","bill","mike","Bill","MIKE");
   
    Map<String, Long> collect = listdemo.stream().map(**String::toLowerCase**).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e->e,Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println("collector printing is : "+collect);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For UppperCase

`val originalList = arrayListOf("apple", "banana", "cherry")`

`val upperCaseList = originalList.map { it.toUpperCase() }`

For LowerCase

`val originalList = arrayListOf("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry")`

`val lowerCaseList = originalList.map { it.toLowerCase() }`